# Check if package installation is required while running code via source()?

Tags: r, install.packages

I am running several scripts in RStudio and checking syntax errors. I am using source() in a loop to perform those tasks. In some scripts, `install.packages("packagename")` occurs. My problem is that when i have the required packages already installed in my computer, a message pops up asking me to update the library. In these cases, I would like to be able to "ignore" `install.packages("packagename")` call and running code to continue without showing any message.

So, how can i check if package installation is required or not while running code via source()?

Comment: maybe `require()`does what you look for?

Comment: Thank you, but i think that it is not enough. if i edit each script, i can add require() as you suggest and it works. But i am running the code via source(). I'm looking for a solution not requiring me to edit each script.

Comment: In each of your scripts, do you have the `install.packages("")` calls for each package?

Comment: No @VitaminB16. There are have 16 different scripts. In some scripts, one or more packages are called directly with library("") but in other cases install.packages("") are called first.

Comment: @maluicr, you *should* edit those scripts.  They are broken if they are calling `install.packages` unnecessarily, and you should fix them.

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a hack, but given the location `file`, this will list all the packages inside the script:

```
require(readr)
require(stringr)
listPackages <- function(file)
{
  r <- readr::read_file(file)
  r = str_replace_all(r, '\\"', "") # remove all quote marks
  packages <- str_extract_all(r, regex("(install.packages|library|require|p_load)\\([:alnum:]*\\)*", multiline = TRUE))[[1]]
  return(unique(gsub("\\(", "", str_extract(packages, regex("\\([:alnum:]*", multiline = F)))))
}
```

---

### Example

test.R:

```r
library("ggplot2")
library(stats)
require("cowplot")
require(MASS)

add <- function(x,y) {x+y}

install.packages("cowplot")
p_load(dplyr)
p_load("dplyr")
```

```r
listPackages("test.R")
# [1] "ggplot2" "stats"   "cowplot" "MASS"    "cowplot" "dplyr"
```

Comment: thank you, works nice, but still doesn't solve my problem.  probably i must rewrite it. thanks anyway. in your code, i believe 'stringr' package is also required.

Comment: I suggest that you edit all of your scripts to use `pacman::p_load(X)` to load a library `X`. If `X` is not installed, it is equivalent to `install.packages("X"); library(X)`. If `X` is installed, it is equivalent to `library(X)`.

Comment: Then you can also do e.g. `p_load("ggplot2","stats","cowplot")` to load/install several packages at once.